# How can I convert my .htaccess to web.config?

Tags: php, .htaccess, iis, web-config

I need to change this `.htaccess` to `web.config`. Server is IIS and I want my PHP application to run on my server

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(application|modules|plugins|system|themes) index.php/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have IIS installed, open the manager, click any site, click URL Rewrite, select import rules on the right panel and paste in your .htaccess rules:

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Imported Rule 1">
       <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
      <conditions>
         <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
    <add input="{R:1}" pattern="^(index.php|robots.txt)" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php/{R:1}" />
</rule>
<rule name="Imported Rule 2" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^(application|modules|plugins|system|themes)" ignoreCase="false" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```